# How to access AfxGetMainWnd() from CWinThread?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm trying to create a worker thread in a class called ClientManager, but I can't get access to AfxGetMainWnd() from the new CWinThread, i.e:

```
UINT ClientManager::WorkerThreadProc( LPVOID param ){
    ClientManager *pThis = reinterpret_cast<ClientManager*>(param);
    return pThis -> DoThreadJob();
}
UINT ClientManager::DoThreadJob(){
    createClientSession("1");
    return 0;
}

void ClientManager::createThread(){
    m_clientManagerThread = AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc,this,0,0,0,NULL);           
}

void ClientManager::createClientSession(CString clientID){
    if (AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd()== NULL){
        _cprintf("NULL");
    }
}
```

Output: NULL

AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd() works in the main thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waas15s1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) says:

> If AfxGetMainWnd is called from the application's primary thread, it returns the application's main window according to the above rules. If the function is called from a secondary thread in the application, the function returns the main window associated with the thread that made the call.

So you need to make the call from the main thread. Do this just before you call `AfxBeginThread` and store the resulting window handle in a member of `ClientManager`. Then your thread can gain access to the window handle via its `ClientManager` reference.

Answer (score 5):

AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd() works in threads.

No need to store the window handle in a member of ClientManager.

Comment: This seems to work for us. Any pitfall from using this solution? Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: The OP asked this in year 2011. It's now 2016.  It works simple because the m_pMainWnd is set in InitInstance(), and normally live until the application window ist destroyed.

Comment: I'm using your solution but I'm wondering if there is any unseen problems from your solution

Comment: Glad to see you use my solution. Again there is no problem, as long as you don't change the m_pMainWnd.